# C++ Lambda: Access static method in lambda leads to error 'this was not captured for this lambda function'

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda

Consider the following code:

```
//this is what I want to call; I cannot modify its signature
void some_library_method(void(*fp)(void));

class Singleton{
    public:
        static Singleton *instance();
        void foo();
        void bar();
    private:
        Singleton();
};

void Singleton::foo(){
    //this leads to an error ('this' was not captured for this lambda function)
    void(*func_pointer)(void) = []{
        Singleton::instance()->bar();
    };
    some_library_method(func_pointer);
}
```

I want to call a function I cannot modify (see `some_library_method`above) which expects a function pointer as an argument. The call should be done in a class member `foo()`. I do know that I cannot access class members there, but all I want to do is access the Class Singleton in a static way (retrieve the singleton instance).

Is there any way reform the lambda expression to show the target compiler, g++ v4.7.2, that it really does **not** need a reference to `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following work-around works:

```
template< typename T > T* global_instance() { return T::instance(); }

void(*func_pointer)(void) = []{
    global_instance<Singleton>()->bar();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a locally defined regular function instead of a lambda for that

```
void Singleton::foo() {
    struct T {
        static void cb(){ Singleton::instance()->bar(); }
    };
    some_library_method(T::cb);
}
```

Comment: `T` seems like a poor name choice for that type.

Comment: @Yakk: IMO `LocalStructureNeededBecauseCppDoesntAllowLocalFunctions` would have been worse :-)

Comment: @muffel: Unfortunately local structures cannot be used with templates for an explicit limitation specified in the standard that I don't understand and that was present in C++03 and has been IIRC inherited also by C++11. Still you can use them to declare local callbacks without having to place the callback code far from the use and without polluting the module namespace.

Comment: Why oh why are the semantics of a lambda any different from those of an inline struct...

Comment: @Cuadue: lambdas (closures) can access locals and this is **very** powerful in general (just happens of not being needed in this case). Unfortunately to really appreciate the full power of reference-capturing closures the language needs to provide garbage-collect based lifetime for locals (not only stack based lifetime) but this would have been too much of a change for C++.