# Does this lambda implicitly capture `this`?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

My linter claims that the lambda in the following code implicitly captures `this` (and wants to have that capture specified explicitly). Is that correct?

```
template <class X>
struct OtherTemplate
{
  static X bar()
  {
    return 1;
  }
};

template <class Y>
struct Test
{
  void foo()
  {
    auto lambda = [&]() {
      // return (Y)1;
      // return std::min<Y>(1, 2);
      return OtherTemplate<Y>::bar();
    };
    (void)lambda;
  }
};

// Explicit instantiation
template struct Test<int>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cvV59J

There is no complaint if the lambda has no default capture, or if any of the commented lines are used instead. Removing the "templatedness" from `OtherTemplate` also produces no diagnostic.

It seems obvious to me that `this` is not used in the lambda. However, the following two questions seem to have observed similar behavior:

- [C++ Lambda: Access static method in lambda leads to error 'this was not captured for this lambda function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514703/c-lambda-access-static-method-in-lambda-leads-to-error-this-was-not-captured)
- [error using static method in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844642/error-using-static-method-in-lambda/)

The C++11 standard (to pick one) indicates to me that capturing `this` would require ODR-using `this` ([`[expr.prim.lambda]/11`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.prim.lambda#11)). I don't see how that happens here, but I've been surprised before by the technicalities of template name lookups.

---

**Edit:** Due to discussions in the comments, I would like to emphasize the following note from the standard, in particular the *can*:

> Implicit odr-uses of `this` can result in implicit capture.

That should make clear that a capture default does not unilaterally capture `this`.

---

So before I file a bug with the linter, I wanted to make sure:
**Does the above lambda implicitly capture `this`?**

I am most interested in C++17, but I would appreciate answers also covering the other standard versions.

Comment: @ThomasSablik could you expand? Like the OP I also can't see how `this` is ODR-used within the lambda, unless the implicit instantiation of `OtherTemplate<Y>` from the scope of a member function for some reason implies ODR-using `this`. My guess would be that this is a false positive from the linter, but I'm interested in hearing from some of the language lawyer experts on this topic.

Comment: @Peter I don't see how you conclude that from the quoted text. That paragraph only states "you can't do `[&, &myVar]` or `[=, myVar]`, only `[&, myVar]` and `[=, &myVar]`". It takes absolutely no stance on what is captured with default captures. Take note that it says "of the form", not "`this` is captured".

Comment: The following note from [\[expr.prim.lambda.capture\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-2) of the C++17 standard draft is kind of interesting though [**emphasis** mine]: _"Note: The form `[&,this]` is **redundant** but accepted for compatibility with ISO C++ 2014.  — end note"_. This would imply that (as of C++17) explicitly capturing `this` as a _simple-capture_ is redundant _no matter the use of `this` in the body of the lambda_? Which in turn would apply `this` is always implicitly captured for a _capture-default_-only capture list of `[&]`?

Comment: [\[expr.prim.lambda.capture\]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#2) has some useful notes/example code.

Comment: `this->static_method()` is valid. Your linter should turn the call that way...

Comment: @Jarod42 I've been thinking along those lines, but there is no static method in `this`. The static method is in a _different_ template. Now, that template instantiation happens to be dependent (so internally the linter puts a `this` in front of everything?), which seems to be what causes this.

Comment: Misread, I thought it was base class call (maybe as your linter ;-) ).

Comment: I don't think you ever implicitly capture `this` from a standard point-of-view. The standard seems to always speak about implicitly capturing `*this`, even when you use `[&]`. In particular, in lambda/13 you have *"A lambda-expression with an associated capture-default that does not explicitly capture `*this` [...] is said to implicitly capture the entity (i.e., `*this` or a variable) if the compound-statement: 1) odr-uses (3.2) the entity (in the case of a variable), or 2) odr-uses (3.2) `this` (in the case of the object designated by `*this`), or 3) [...]"*. (N4594)

Comment: @dfri C++17 allows capturing `*this` (i.e. the lambda operating on a copy of the class, not just holding a copy of the `this` pointer), whereas C++14 did not. That's what that compatibility is essentially about. But the comments here are not the place to unpack that.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I interpret the note as applying to particularly to `[&, this]` (and not "`[&, &this]` or `[=, this]` and so on). [P0806r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0806r0.html) explicitly visits this example a _reference capture_, not value capture of `*this`: _"If the default capture is reference capture, the hypothetical “`[&, &*this]`” (in real C++: `[&, this]`) is a redundant reference capture_". I still believe your linter is wrong, but I think this note is peculiar.

Comment: ... the note was added as part of [P0018R3: Lambda Capture of `*this` by Value as `[=,*this]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0018r3.html), though, so you're probably right. I will stop unpacking this thread in this comment thread. Thanks for the feedback.